# How to define a DataTemplate in code?

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid, silverlight-3.0, datatemplate

How can I create a `DataTemplate` in code (using C#) and then add a control to that `DataTemplate`?

```
<data:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border>
            <Border Margin="10" Padding="10" BorderBrush="SteelBlue" 
                 BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="5">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                     FontSize="10">
                </TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</data:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

I am using Sivlerlight.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way to create a `DataTemplate` in Silverlight is to use [XamlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190359(VS.95).aspx). Basically you would just pass it the XAML as a string and it will give you back a `DataTemplate`. Byron's solution would apply to WPF but Silverlight (to the best of my knowledge) does not support `FrameworkElementFactory`.

[Scott Morrison: Defining Silverlight DataGrid Columns at Runtime](http://blogs.msdn.com/scmorris/archive/2008/04/14/defining-silverlight-datagrid-columns-at-runtime.aspx)

Take note of option #2 for `DataGridTemplateColumn`.

Comment: +1 This is correct.  Personally I prefer to use LinqToXml objects to build the Xaml needed but ultimately a result string needs to be passed to XamlReader to create a DataTemplate programmatically.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a control like a `TextBlock` using a `FrameworkElementFactory`. Then you can add the `TextBlock`to the VisualTree of the `DataTemplate`. Like so:

```
//Create binding object and set as mode=oneway
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("SomePropertyPathName");
binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;

//get textblock object from factory and set binding
FrameworkElementFactory textElement = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
textElement.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);

//apply textblock to datatemplate
dataTemplate.VisualTree = textElement;
```

Comment: The OP says he's using Silverlight which as far as I know does not support FrameworkElementFactory.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a good article over at MSDN: "[Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx#defining_simple_datatemplate)." I would start there.

**Update**: Eh, scratch that. I read over your requirement for "in code." I'll just leave the link here for whoever might stumble upon this post.